# Potassium permanganate and hydrogen peroxide decomposition

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I saw a reaction by chemicalforce on YouTube where he decomposed $\ce{H2O2}$ into $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$ using potassium permanganate. The permanganate is a catalyst in the reaction.

I am wondering if this decomposition occurs because the initial $\ce{H2O2}$ decomposition reacts with the $\ce{KMnO4}$ and reproduces $\ce{H2O2}$ which then again decomposes?

How is the permanganate a catalyst?

Comment: Permanganate is not exactly a catalyst here, it gets destroyed as well.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43256/why-is-the-reaction-between-potassium-permanganate-and-hydrogen-peroxide-spontan

Answer (score 1):

Potassium permanganate is involved in two ways.

It oxidizes hydrogen peroxide to oxygen:

$$\ce{2 MnO4- + 3 H2O2 -> 2 MnO2 + 2 OH- + 3 O2 + 2 H2O}$$

The formed $\ce{MnO2}$ acts as the catalyst of reaction:

$$\ce{2 H2O2 ->[MnO2] 2 H2O + O2}$$

Comment: Hello Poutnik! Is it a mistake to call the first reaction a disproportionation? The oxidation state of oxygen goes down (to $-2$ in $\ce{H2O}$) and goes up (to $0$ in $\ce{O2}$). Or calling it a redox reaction is more accurate in this case?

Comment: You would not need permanganate for it.